# What would the query be for the following sample table?

Tags: sql, union-all

Can you please help me with a query that would display a table like this:

```
Dept_ID                Dept_Name

10                     Admin
10                     Whalen
20                     Sales
20                     James
20                     King
20                     Smith
40                     Marketing
40                     Neena
```

and so on...The Schema is HR

Display the Department Id and the Department Name and then the subsequent employees last names working under that department

Comment: Why union-all? this is only select query

Comment: either this is a very basic query and you should just read a tutorial, or it's more complicated that it seems and you should describe your database schema and what you tried as query if you want help.

Comment: The short answer is `don't`.  You want the `dept_name` column to hold both the department name and employee last names?  That's a fundamentally broken design.  You should at-least have another column called something like `type` that explains what this row describes (a department or an employee).  But even better department names should be in a different column to employee names.  If this is about formatting the results for display, format them in your application...

Comment: @thescion because that's im asked to do...except if i use union all i dont get the right ordering

Comment: @MatBailie I got that except we had this as part of out test and the display was exactly as i have shown we didn't have a a separate column for employee names

Comment: @MatBailie Suppose i used this query

SELECT department_id, department_name
FROM departments
UNION
select DEPARTMENT_ID, LAST_NAME
FROM employees;

This gives me the output but i do not how to sort it in a manner that would display each employee only after their department name

Comment: @AsimKhan See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you union two data sets, there is NO implicit ordering, you could get the results in any order.

The get a particular order you *must* use `ORDER BY`.

To use `ORDER BY`, then you *must* have fields to do that ordering by.

In your case, the pseudo code would be...
- `ORDER BY [dept_id], [depts-then-employees], [dept_name]`

The middle of those three is something that YOU are going to have to create.

One way of doing that is as follows.

***note***: Just because you have a field to order by, does not mean that you have to select it.

```
SELECT
    dept_id,
    dept_name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        d.dept_id,
        d.dept_name,
        0   AS entity_type_ordinal
    FROM
        department   d

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        d.dept_id,
        e.employee_name,
        1    AS entity_type_ordinal
    FROM
        department   d
    INNER JOIN
        employee     e
            ON  e.dept_id = d.dept_id
)
   dept_and_emp
ORDER BY
   dept_id,
   entity_type_ordinal,
   dept_name
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Mat!
I got this in a test and i had absolutely no clue and ive been racking my brain ever since then :/

Is this something that comes with experience or was it straight forward and i just din't understand it? Is it a low level code?

Comment: @AsimKhan - If any of the answers here helped, please up-vote them and/or mark them as accepted answers :)  As for how low-level or difficult, the hardest part is understanding that in SQL the is ***never*** an inherent order to data, you need to use `ORDER BY` and so you need to have *something* to doing the ordering by.  I'd say that's simple-to-medium level of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Dept_ID, Dept_Name
FROM Your_Table
```

Simple as I can make it. It's very difficult (near impossible) to tell exactly what the query should be without more detail in terms of your table structure and some sample data.

From your edit, you may need something more like this;

```
SELECT DT.Dept_ID, DT.Dept_Name, ET.Emp_Name
FROM Dept_Table AS DT INNER JOIN Emp_Table AS ET ON DT.Dept_ID = ET.Dept_ID
ORDER BY Dept_ID
```

This shows the employees in each department on the next column, you don't really want all that in the same column.

Comment: I expected as much Asim, please edit your post with more detail as I have described in my answer and I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: @AsimKhan - For anyone to have *any* hope of helping you, you need to give more information.  `doesn't produce the output required` is extremely unhelpful unless you explain what output you got and in what manner it was not what you expected / required.  As for your question; you need to tell us what tables you have, how they're related, what about your desired results example is important (ordering, formatting, etc).  You may as well be saying `I need to win` without explaining what game you're playing.

Comment: @MatBailie The query i got from William will only give me the department id and department name not all the employees working in that department...which i want displayed under the department name

I am using HR schema
There is a departments table and an employees table, which i'm pretty sure is all we need

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a table in your database called `departments` that holds this information, your code might look like this:

```
select 
  dept_id, dept_name
from
  departments
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display certain columns of the table like you have asked in the question above , you can use the following syntax :

> select column_names from table_name

replace:

1. column_names with the column names you want to display separated by a coma
   2.table_name with the name of the table whose columns you wish to display

   for the above question , the following code will do:

> select Dept_Id , Dept_Name from Department ;

The above code works if your table name is 'Department'